# Ethernet won't connect (18.04.2)

Tags: networking, ethernet

I left my computer running for an hour or two, idle, and when I logged back in, the ethernet connection was stuck on "connecting." I should probably mention that I installed some tools with Katoolin, which may have messed with my network settings. What steps should I take, beyond router reset, unplugging/replugging the cable, and restarting network-manager? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked to ensure the connection isn't still there? Sometimes the UI gets confused and says connecting when it's established. Run `ifconfig -a` to check and see if the Ethernet interface has an IP address. Also, what version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: I'm on 18.04.2. Will edit the post accordingly.

Comment: Ifconfig spits out a value for inet6 but no recognizable ipv4 address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the system wasn't loading the network driver, so the interface wasn't detected. `sudo modprobe r8169` appears to have fixed it.