# Ubuntu 18.04 ethernet won't connect

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, ethernet

My Ubuntu 18.04 refuses to connect to internet via ethernet.
No matter what I do and try, my internet connection seems to not work 90% of the time, and I don't have a wifi adapter.

I tried this solution: [Ethernet won't connect (18.04.2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119381/ethernet-wont-connect-18-04-2) - and it worked... once. And then never again.

For the record, my ethernet cable is plugged into a router on the other end, and router is using a mobile LTE internet that is somewhat unreliable. And I did mess with settings trying to fix it, but problem has persisted since the very beginning of installation - though previously internet sometimes worked, and lately it appears to p much never work.

Trying to `ping 8.8.8.8`
results in:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Typing `ifconfig -a` results in:

```
enp3s4f0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 9c:8e:99:35:15:80  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  

enp3s4f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5db5:ba12:c784:52de  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9c:8e:99:35:15:81  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10  bytes 736 (736.0 B)
        RX errors 168  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 407
        TX packets 133  bytes 23931 (23.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1373  bytes 97213 (97.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1373  bytes 97213 (97.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Typing `sudo service networking start` resulted in this:

```
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Typing these commands resulted in:

typing `systemctl status networking.service`

```
networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-09-08 13:48:04 CEST; 2min 44s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 2560 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2558 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environmen
 Main PID: 2560 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

wrz 08 13:48:04 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
wrz 08 13:48:04 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p sh[2558]: /etc/network/interfaces:2: misplaced option
wrz 08 13:48:04 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p sh[2558]: ifquery: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfac
wrz 08 13:48:04 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p ifup[2560]: /etc/network/interfaces:2: misplaced option
wrz 08 13:48:04 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p ifup[2560]: /sbin/ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/int
wrz 08 13:48:04 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, statu
wrz 08 13:48:04 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
wrz 08 13:48:04 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
```

typing `journalctl -xe`

```
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p megasync[2307]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (devic
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p upowerd[1066]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/000
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p update-notifier[2305]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p gnome-software[2303]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE 
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p gnome-terminal-[2125]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p nautilus-deskto[1837]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p gsd-media-keys[1781]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE 
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p gsd-keyboard[1770]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (d
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p transmission-gt[1834]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p gsd-color[1767]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (devi
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p gsd-clipboard[1759]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p gsd-xsettings[1742]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p gsd-power[1724]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (devi
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1163]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1163]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd fo
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p gsd-wacom[1743]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (devi
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p gnome-shell[1573]: gdk_device_update_tool: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (de
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1163]: (EE) systemd-logind: failed to relea
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p upowerd[1066]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/000
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p upowerd[1066]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/000
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p upowerd[1066]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/000
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p upowerd[1066]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/000
wrz 08 14:44:58 shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p upowerd[1066]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/000
```

my etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
pre-up /usr/sbin/ethtool --change enp3s4f1 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

"wrz" is Polish acronym for September btw.

At this point I don't know what to do anymore, and I'm considering a reinstall.

EDIT: Okay, it seems it actually does sometime connect, but only some time (20-30 minutes) after starting Ubuntu. I'm note sure if this is related to typing `sudo modprobe r8169` I am completely baffled now.

EDIT 2 (09.09.2019) Okay, so. I'm running Ubuntu Desktop. There is an Ethernet cable that goes directly from my router, TPLINK TL-MR3220, to my computer. The router has a mobile 4G LTE Huawei modem plugged directly into it via USB. I don't have wifi adapter so connecting wirelessly is not currently an option.

I commented out /etc/network/interfaces, rebooted and typed `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5715 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:03:04.0
       logical name: enp3s4f0
       version: a3
       serial: 9c:8e:99:35:15:80
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pcix pm vpd msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=5715-v3.29, UMP 1.23 latency=64 link=no mingnt=64 multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:32 memory:f9ff0000-f9ffffff memory:f9fe0000-f9feffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5715 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 4.1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:04.1
       logical name: enp3s4f1
       version: a3
       serial: 9c:8e:99:35:15:81
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pcix pm vpd msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=5715-v3.29 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=64 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:33 memory:f9fd0000-f9fdffff memory:f9fc0000-f9fcffff
```

Then I typed `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Also I checked contents of `crontab -e` (without editing anything) and aside from the comment, only line is:

```
@reboot dhclient -r eth$ && dhclient eth$
```

It seems I am sometimes able to get a connection after typing `sudo modprobe r8169` but it seems to only work sometimes, or after some time passes.

And typing `dhclient enp3s4f1` returns

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

Typing it again with `sudo` appears to run it succesfully, but nothing happens. I tried the other ethernet port, with the same results.

EDIT 3: Unplugging the cable, shutting the computer down, restarting and then plugging it in anew seems to connect everything perfectly and instantly.

Comment: Please add the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`... there seams to be a wrong option in there. Have you tried `dhclient enp3s4f0` or `dhclient enp3s4f1`?

Comment: Would try shutdown and then disconnect cable from computer. restart and then plug cable back in.  If it works you might have to use an older driver.

Comment: Your /etc/network/interfaces file is invalid. You're not getting an ipv4 address. Comment out your pre-up command, reboot, and edit your question with the results of `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Please describe your network cabling from the computer port to the router/modem. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them.

Comment: @SimonSudler Since I somehow got a connection now, the content of /etc/network/interfaces is now a direct copypaste from the file. Also I'm gonna try these on next reboot.

Comment: Also, is this a Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server installation?

Comment: @heynnema I updated the question with all the information you requested, see "EDIT 2".

Comment: @crip659 I had zero hopes but this has somehow worked perfectly. Please tell me how to solve this permanently, I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: I had same problem and looked arounded to fixed it because did not like the idea of unplugging and plugging in the cable all the time, not good for plug life.  Found then the answer was that the new driver was causing problems and had to install older driver and block new driver.  Tried looking around for what I did, but can't find it right now and don't know enough to guide you.  Hopefully one of the more knowledgeable people on here can help.  Need your r8169 dropped back to using r8168 I think to fix.  Might need to ask new question if you don't get response.

Comment: `sudo modprobe r8169` has nothing to do with your configuration, as your ethernet uses the `tg3` driver. Your f1 interface is only doing a 10Mb connection to your router, instead of 1Gb, and also not getting an ipv4 address. This suggests a cabling or auto-negotiation problem. Are you using cat 5E or cat 6 ethernet cables? Is the router capable of gig LAN connections? Have you rebooted the router? I'm out of town until Thu, and I'll check back then,

Comment: Also, can you check your BIOS version? `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for a newer version.

Comment: @shinobody I'm back in town. Status please...

Comment: @heynnema Okay, so.
On the cable it says it's a Cat5E.
I rebooted the router many times, it's my default solution for connection problems. Nothing happens when I do that.
When I typed the bios command you asked for, all I get is "W08" and I don't know what to do with that.
However, I found a temporary solution - just like other commenter suggested, plugging the ethernet cable in *while the system is already running* does result in a connection. It only doesn't work if I leave the cable plugged in at boot.

Comment: @shinobody plz answer the questions from my last two comments.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry, I accidentally pressed "enter" instead of "shift+enter" when writing the comment. I answered the questions now.

Comment: @heynnema Oh yeah, and the gig LAN connections - I have no idea. Producers website doesn't mention anything at all about that.

Comment: Take the W08 BIOS version, and go to the manufacturer's web site with your model # and check in the downloads sections for a newer BIOS. I checked the spec on your router, and it's only 10/100 LAN ports. You're getting a 10Mb connection. Try `sudo ethtool -s enp3s4f1 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off` and `sudo dhclient enp3s4f1`. Then check `sudo lshw -C network` for the `size` parameter and it should be 100Mb. Then `ip a` should show an ipv4 address. Reboot and see what happens.

Comment: @heynnema There isn't a BIOS update - it seems HP doesn't even list this product in its discontinued list - but it doesn't matter because these commands solved it! Size is 100 just like you said, and `ip a` shows a correct ipv4 address. I rebooted it twice, and got a connection on startup both times.  Thank you so fricking much, and thanks for putting up with my inexperience, lol.
I'm not sure about the etiquette on this site - do you want to write the answer or should I do that?

Comment: @shinobody Glad it's working for you now. I wrote an answer. Please remember to accept it for me. Thanks! Give me the make/model # of your machine and I'll look for a BIOS update for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

I checked the specs on your router, and it's only got 10/100 LAN ports. You're getting a 10Mb connection. I suspect a cable problem, or a auto-negotiation problem. Try...

`sudo ethtool -s enp3s4f1 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off`

`sudo dhclient enp3s4f1`

Then check `sudo lshw -C network` for the `size` parameter and it should be `100Mb`. Then `ip a` should show an ipv4 address. Reboot and confirm that it's still working as expected.

Also, edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` file and remove...

`pre-up /usr/sbin/ethtool --change enp3s4f1 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off`

and add...

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```